# Check for same values in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I Have a nested array. They both have a value called name.
name can be A or B. Now I want to compare all elements and want to get true if all are either A or B.

Inputs:

```
[
  {
    "arr": {
      "teachers": [
        {
          "name": "A"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "arr2": {
      "teachers": [
        {
          "name": "B"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to check if all foo values are the same.

**I have a solution but it looks ugly because I have to put the 'A':**

```
const foo = this.arr.map(i => i.teachers.every(j => j.name.includes('A')));
const foo2 = foo.every(e => e === foo[0]);
```

Comment: Running the same code inside the platform snippet throws the error i.teachers is undefined. Map is not flattening your array or in other words, is not mapping the nested array. You need to use either a recursive solution or use another built-in method to flatten the array first and then check if all the values are either A or B

Answer (score 0):

You could map to an array of names, create a Set out of it and check it's size:

```
 const names = arr.flatMap(it => it.teachers.map(teacher => teacher.name));

 (new Set(names)).size === 1
```

Alternatively you could compare the first name against all others:

```
  names.every(it => it === names[0])
```

Comment: Wouldn't the size be 2?

Comment: flatMap is experimental. Would be risky to use

Comment: @matt I read "Now I want to compare all elements and want to get true if all are either A or B." as mutually exclusive "all A" or "all B".

Comment: @sarah no. It is specified and supported by all runtimes (except IE). If you need better support, use polyfills.

Comment: @JonasWilms es2019 we use es2018 I can't use flatMaps :(

Comment: @sarah then it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: It's not my project :(

Comment: @JonasWilms this one does not give me the output I want. My solution is fine, but it's not flexible.

Answer (score 0):

First get a single `name` of `teacher`. Then check all names against the compare value.

```
const
    compareValue = Object.values(array[0])[0].teachers[0].name,
    hasSameName = array.every(o =>
        Object.values(o)[0].teachers.every(({ name }) => name === compareValue)
    );
```